# I'm confused about 2 different outputs, as setTimeout is asynchronous, fn definition should get updated to '2' by the time callback executes

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

If I change the second function expression to function declaration then both the timeouts will log '1' which is completely understandable from the hoisting pov, but here as we're using function expression so as per me second definition should override the first one by the time callback executes in both timeouts.

```
    var fn = function () {
      console.log('1');
    };
    
    setTimeout(fn, 1000); //output: 1
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
     fn();               
    }, 1000);  //output: 2
    
    fn = function () {
      console.log('2');
    };
```

Comment: `setTimeout(fn, 1000)` schedules the function itself that is *currently* referenced by the variable `fn`. Reassigning the variable doesn't change the function object.

Answer (score 1):

This is confusing, since it requires deep understanding on how js handles javascript.

Your code has two timeouts. When the first one is run, the in JS event loop (which handles timeout function), function fn is set to be run in 1000ms.

At this moment, function fn logs `1`, so inside the event loop, javascript engine will plan to run function `console.log('1')` in 1000ms.

This part seems obvious. If then, what is different about the second setTimeout?

Well, `()=>{fn()}` specifically means that function `fn` should be **found** and executed.

Hence,

```
    setTimeout(()=>{
     fn();               
    }, 1000);
```

means: After 1000ms, function `fn` should be found, and then executed. Therefore, if `fn` has changed in the meantime, the updated version will be executed.

This is different from the first setTimeout, where the actual content of `fn` is set to be executed in 1000ms, not **whatever function that is named as 'fn'** at that point.

That is why the second timeout function will run the updated version of `fn`

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP especially mentioned hoisting:
Hoisting is when a variable or function declaration is moved to the top of the file before execution of script. For variables only the definition is moved up and their values are still undefined. Whereas function declarations are hoisted at top.

Here you have function expressions, which are similar to variables and their values will not be hoisted.
So step wise :

In line 1, fn gets the value.
In line 2, setTimeout gets a function to run, which is fn. (Same is executed in the future)
In line 3, setTimeout gets a function to run, which is not fn **instead a function that will call fn**.
Then line 4 is executed, where the value of fn will change.

Note: If both the function expression would have been declarations instead, then 2 will be printed both times.

```
 function fn() {
      console.log('2');
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoisting is irrelevant in this case as the reassignment is happening before you run `fn()` in the second timeout. It does matter if both were a function declaration (i will explain in a bit).

I think you do understand whats happening in your code, but just to get on the same page:

1. You declare AND assign a function to the `fn` variable.
2. You trigger the `setTimeout` while passing it a direct reference to the `fn` function from step 1.
3. You trigger a second `setTimeout` and pass it a reference to a new function, note that this new function is "closing over" that `fn` variable, meaning that if you change this variable before the function is executed it will pick up the change.
4. You reassign `fn` variable with a new function (remember the note from previous step?).
5. Synchronous code is finnished, so its time to pass the async code back to our call stack.
6. The function we passed to the first timeout is now running (remember, we passed a reference) and loging `1`.
7. The function we passed to the second timeout is now running, it "picks up" the change that you made in step 4 to the `fn` variable and execute the "new" `fn` function, hence `2` is logged to the console.

Now, you mentioned hoisting, as you can see hoisting isn't relevant in your specific case, because only the variable declaration is hoisted and not the assignment. However, it does matter if one (or both) of the functions were function declaration instead of expression.

i.e:

```js
function fn(){...}
```

Lets say we change your code to this:

```js
function fn() {
  console.log('1');
};

setTimeout(fn, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  fn();
}, 1000);

function fn() {
  console.log('2');
};
```

In this case you will get the number `2` logged twice in console. This is due to the fact that function declaration are hoisted including both the declaration of the variable and the assignment of the function.

So its like the engine will run it like that:

```js
function fn() {
  console.log('1');
};

function fn() {
  console.log('2');
};

setTimeout(fn, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  fn();
}, 1000);
```

We basically reassigning the `fn` variable before we run any function.

Imagine that only the reassginment was a function declaration:

```js
var fn = function() {
  console.log('1');
};

setTimeout(fn, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  fn();
}, 1000);

function fn() {
  console.log('2');
};
```

In this case we woud see the number `1` logged twice in console. This is due to the fact that function declaration are hoisted above function expressions (its not 100% accurate, but lets keep it simple). So our code would run by the engine like that:

```js
function fn() {
  console.log('2');
};

var fn = function() {
  console.log('1');
};


setTimeout(fn, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  fn();
}, 1000);
```

Hope that helps clarify the consfusion you had.